# Howto get rid of directory prefix in Java webserver url?

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat, jetty

I am using Maven with Jetty / Tomcat. My pom.xml declares the ID of my application as `<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>`. Consequently, all my webapp source is located in `src/main/java/webapp`. Now, whenever I run any of the webserver, my URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/index.html
```

and I haven't found a clue that tells me how to get rid of the application or dir name and make the URL look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean using the `jetty:run` and `tomcat:run` mojos (if not, please specify what you mean):

In Jetty, use the [contextPath](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#contextPath) argument:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- version omitted -->
    <configuration>
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        <!-- other config -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In Tomcat it's the [path](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#path) argument

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Version omitted -->
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <!-- Other configuration -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways you could do this:

- In Tomcat, rename the `webapp.war` to `ROOT.war` (note the capitalization)
- Configure Apache on top of that and create a rewrite rule for pointing root to correct webapp.
- Use Jetty's [contextPath](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#contextPath)